# BGUI change color for Text_Input

Tags: game-engine

how can I change the color of the text_input widget in the BGUI?

I've tried:

```
self.input = bgui.TextInput(self.win, text="text", color=(0, 0, 0, 1), size=[.4, .04], pos=[.04, 0.12],
        input_options = bgui.BGUI_INPUT_NONE, options = bgui.BGUI_DEFAULT)
```

but it didn't work, the color is still white. In the default theme the TextInput color is set to black too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for [BGUI](https://github.com/Moguri/bgui/tree/master/bgui), it appears that the color parameter is not being used in text_input.py. Your best option is to use theme to customize the input text color.